# How can disable some dates in the date picker

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I kind of think this isn't possible, but interested in some elegant workarounds.  I have a report in SSRS, which has a "From" date, and a "To" date.  For various reasons, it's important to not let users select dates larger than a certain value.  Is it possible to customize the date parameters in any way?

My hope was to adjust some dates as greyed out, for example any date past yyyy-mm-dd is not valid, and therefore greyed out.

I've tried looking at Properties->Available Values, but doing this just makes the date parameter a dropdown, which is not what I want.  Another other solutions that I can try?  Thank you very much!

Our parameters:
[image]

Looking at "Available Values" in the properties window:
[image]

Unfortunately only gives a dropdown of the 1 value I entered, where I still need to keep the date picker customizable to any date (obviously with the hope that I can disable/greyout certain dates):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed correctly, this isn't possible with the default datepicker.

A custom UI for report parameter selection would be the only way to meet your design requirements, using a datepicker of your choice. Parameters can be passed for report execution either through the [report URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153563.aspx), [ReportViewer control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251669.aspx), or using the [SOAP API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155376.aspx).

Comment: You could add some code to your report query so that the main query is not executed if the parameter dates fall outside the date range. You could also add an optionally hidden textbox that is displayed if the user selects dates outside the range.